# How to pass variable from one JS file to the other from within a deferred function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call json object in another JS file but there seems to be a timing issue. So I put a setTimeout below but the setTiemout runs twice, first with the object populated, then again with the object undefined and then undefined the passed to the second JS file. I also tried clearTimeout but then it didn't run at all. Then I tried a boolean but it still ran twice. I think the issue might be cause of the deferred, is there any way around this?

```
var json = {};
$('.submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $('.url-input');
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(input).val(), 
        data: input.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data) {
            var category;

            $(data).find('a[href*="categories"]').filter(function(){
              var data = $(this);
              category = data.text().trim();

              json.category = category;
            });

            def.resolve();
            return def.promise;
        }
    }).then(function () {

        $('.cust-viz.viz-2').html('<iframe class="bubble_chart" src="bubble_chart.html" height="500"></iframe>');
        if (json.category) {
            hideShowViz('show');
        }

    });
});
}

setTimeout(function () {
   json = json;
}, 5000);
```

based on answers, I did

```
var json ={};
$('.submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = $('.url-input');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(input).val(), 
        data: input.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    }).then(function (data) {
        var category;   
         $(data).find('a[href*="categories"]').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            category = data.text().trim();

            json.category = category;
          });

          if (json.category) {
            $('.cust-viz.viz-2').html('<iframe class="bubble_chart" src="bubble_chart.html" height="500"></iframe>');
            hideShowViz('show');
        }
    });
});
```

}

Still returning empty.

Comment: I looks like in your call back you set the global json.country to your ajax response. Whilst this is all happening you have a timer that will execute 5000ms and wipe the global json with self.json. Which will make it undefined. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the json var in that file in the iframe? I assume the 5000 ms is  so you are waiting for the ajax call to fetch the data. The normal practice would be to call whatever function you have in your other file as a callback in the ajax callback and pass the json object.

Comment: Sorry the setTimeout was posted wrong. I have the json = json because it was returning as an empty object since at the top it is globally defined as empty. I am rusty at JS can you illustrate what you mean? I am accessing the json in the iframe in an embedded script tag.

Comment: Yeah OK. So the reason would be because the code is wrong. The setTimeout will fire in 5 secs and observe the value of json. BUT! If your ajax round call to your server takes longer than 5secs the response would not of set the country prop of json. It's better to execute whatever code you need to update when the ajax call returns ie doSomething(json) within your ajax callback

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code.

Regarding timing, you are likely to have issues with this pattern ...

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: fnA
})
.then(fnB);
```

... especially if `fnB` is dependent on something done by `fnA`.

In practice, it's never good to mix a success handler written as an `$.ajax()` option with one written as a `.then()` callback.

So refactor as follows :

```
$.ajax({
    ...
})
.then(fnA)
.then(fnB);
```

Now,

- if `fnA` is *asynchronous*, it must return a promise to inhibit progress to `fnB` until that promise resolves.
- if `fnA` is wholly *synchronous*, as appears to be the case, you can return a value or , more typically, you would merge `fnA` with `fnB`.

*Note: A success handler written as an `$.ajax()` option does not possess the same power, and that's the reason why we don't mix `success: fn` with `.then()`.*

```
$.ajax({
    ...
})
.then(fnAB);
```

With those rules in mind, you should be able to better debug the other issues.

Comment: not only that, but the `def.promise` returned from `success:` will never work - nothing reads that return value

Comment: So remove the success and do everything in the then()?

Comment: @ModoModo, yes, in essence that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @Alnitak, yes indeed. I've added a sentence to make that clear.

Comment: I did and it is still returning as an empty obj.

Comment: As I said, more debugging is required. My answer addresses only the timing issue.